# Java XML parser without excessive memory allocation

Tags: java, xml, parsing, memory-management

At work I am parsing large XML files using the `DefaultHandler` class. Doing that, I noticed that this interface allocates many `String`s, for element names, attribute names and values, and so on.

From that, I thought about creating an XML parser that only does the absolute minimum of object allocation. Currently I need:

- one StringBuilder for building the element names, attribute names, etc.
- one CharsetDecoder for transforming bytes into chars.

My test program, for parsing http://magnatune.com/info/song_info.xml, looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class XmlParserDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Map<String, String>> allSongs = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("d:/song_info.xml");
    try {
      XmlParser parser = new XmlParser(new BufferedInputStream(fis));
      if (parser.element("AllSongs")) {
        while (parser.element("Track")) {
          Map<String, String> track = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
          while (parser.element()) {
            String name = parser.getElementName();
            String value = parser.text();
            track.put(name, value);
            parser.endElement();
          }
          allSongs.add(track);
          parser.endElement();
        }
        parser.endElement();
      }
    } finally {
      fis.close();
    }
  }
}
```

This code looks better than my experiments with the `XMLEventReader`. Now the only missing part would be the `XmlParser` class mentioned in the code above. Do you know if someone has written that code before? It's really just a pet project of mine, but I'm curious how much the old statement *Object creation is expensive* is worth anymore.

Yes, I know that `LinkedHashMap`s are using much memory. It's really just the parsing part that I want to be memory-efficient. Everything else is just for making a simple example.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? poor performance, parser using too much memory, or something else? If it's performance/memory use it would wise to profile first, before spending time coding up a new parser on the hunch that object allocation is expensive.

Comment: I don't really have a problem, it's more like a puzzle. I want to see how far I can get to avoid memory allocation. It's not that I have the need for it right now, but maybe later, when I really need it, I can use what I learned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Object creation is expensive hasn't been true" for quite a long time in Java. Allocation is usually dirt cheap (move a pointer) and garbage collection has come a long way.

I would *definitely* use an XML API which lets you do what you want easily rather than worrying too much about excessive memory allocation, unless you think you're going to be pushing your performance boundaries.

I'm sure there *are* XML APIs designed to have a particularly small memory footprint - but just how large are your XML files? If they're small enough to fit into memory easily, I'd just not worry about it... and if they're too large for that you really need to be thinking of a streaming API anyway. I suspect the band of sizes where a particularly efficient parser could fit it in memory but a "normal" one couldn't is relatively small, in terms of applicability.

Comment: You convinced me. I read the paper about StAX (at http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/StAX-1_0.pdf) and tried it, and as long as I don't call any unnecessary methods, it's as memory-efficient as I could ever want it.